# discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.help' could not be loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm attempting to transfer all of my commands for my bot to cogs to make handling and sorting easier. I can not get my cogs to load.

I've tried multiple different methods of loading cogs and none have worked, I've attempted using different IDEs which also didn't work.

folder tree

[image]

help.py

```py
class Help(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):
        # Code #


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Help(client))
```

bot.py

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for filename in os.listdir('./commands'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

error

```
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 617, in load_extension
    lib = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cogs'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Seep\bot.py", line 33, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 619, in load_extension
    raise errors.ExtensionNotFound(name, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.help' could not be loaded.
```

Comment: If the cogs.help module is in `commands`, should the `load_extension` be `commands.cogs.help` and not `cogs.help`?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule No, I've already tried this and it didn't work. It returned the same error.

Comment: Can you add in your question what does your app folder tree looks like?

Comment: You don't need `cogs` in filename it's just `commands.help`

Comment: @AlbertoPoljak This works and it loads the cog but it doesn't allow me to use it. It will load it then when I try to use the command it doesn't work.

Comment: @Konyer Are you removing the built-in help command by passing `help_command=None` to `Bot`?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes, I figured it out, it works now. I just need to resolve some issues I'm having with my command itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

simply wouldn't work since you're loading your extension with `cogs.name`.

It should be instead:

```
client.load_extension(f'commands.{filename[:-3]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the reason Discord.py raises this error is because, before the error, it states that `cogs` is not a valid module and therefore it cannot load the cog.

I had the same error and when I commented my import statement it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I solved it by loading the module explicitly via python instead of via discord.py to see if there was an error in my script itself because Discord.py hides these errors during runtime.

```
> python
> help("wlct.cogs.common") <- the module you're trying to load here
problem in wlct.cogs.common - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.requests'
```

After I updated urllib.requests -> urllib.request (type on my part) the issue went away.